# Comodo Antivirus for Linux issue

Tags: upgrade, lubuntu, antivirus

I use Lubuntu 15.04 and, since the last upgrade the system performed (today, Tuesday, September, 29, 2015), the COMODO AntiVirus for Linux left to work in real time mode (the supposed green color shield changed to red with an error message: "FileSystem Filter Driver is not loaded").

How could I work around this?

Comment: 3rd party app. So best to use their forums. Aee http://forums.comodo.com/comodo-antivirus-for-linux-cavl/help-filesystem-filter-driver-is-not-loaded-t105780.0.html for a possible fix.

Comment: Problem solved!!! We have to download the "driver.tar" file from http://www.bondoffamily-net.com/~kinta-chan/techknow/DownLoad/DownLoad.html and run it from a LXTerminal session. Anyway, Thanks a lot for your help!!!

Comment: no problem. make an answer and accept it please when you have the time :)